# Opening a PDF file in Files app returns nil

Tags: ios, pdf

I want to open a pdf file that sits in the Files app on an iOS Device. I have setup everything so when the user selects to open the pdf file with my app the following function gets called:

```
-( BOOL )application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

The path to the file is as below:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/test.pdf
```

however when I go to read the file in my swift code using the following code it returns nil

```
let pdfDoc = CGPDFDocument( pdfURL )
```

Any ideas
Thanks Reza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL is security-scoped bookmarked so one needs to wrap it in url accessing code:

```
if pdfURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {

    let pdfDoc = CGPDFDocument( pdfURL )
    // additional executions
    pdfURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 5 Solution

In case you're looking for more pro active way to get page drawings and exact documents from an pdf URL it's might better way

```
extension URL {

  func getPDFDocument() -> CGPDFDocument? {
    if self.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
      guard let document = CGPDFDocument(self as CFURL) else { return nil }
      self.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
      return document
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```